# R replace empty column of DF with random categorical value

Tags: r, random, categorical-data

Trying to replace demographic values by assigning them randomly.

I can obtain empty gender data rows by carrying out following:

```
df$gender[df$gender == "",]

user_id, name, age, gender
001, xyz, 23,  
004, abc, 32,
```

I want to assign gender randomly:

```
sample(c('male', 'female'), nrow(df$gender[df$gender == ""]), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
```

tried following:

```
df$gender[df$gender == ""] <- sample(c('male', 'female'), nrow(df$gender[df$gender == ""]), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
```

This only assigned to few cells but not all.

Comment: You should use `length` instead of `nrow` or, even better, `sum(df$gender=="",na.rm=TRUE)`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the following example:

```
user_id <- c(1:5)
name <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
age <- c(20,23,44,21,32)
gender <- c("m","f","","", "m")

df <- data.frame(user_id,
                 name,
                 age,
                 gender,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I suggest creating a vector of length nrow:

```
rand_gender <- sample(c('m', 'f'), nrow(df), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
```

And only replacing in case "gender" is empty:

```
df$gender <- ifelse(df$gender=="", rand_gender, df$gender)
```

Comment: does this work with factor column? gender column ended up with numeric values.

Comment: Hi @Null-Hypothesis, you can work with factor columns by using `dplyr::ifelse` like so:

`df$gender <- dplyr::if_else(df$gender=="", as.factor(rand_gender), df$gender)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `length`. `df$gender[df$gender == ""]` returns a vector since you're subsetting `df$gender`. You also don't need `probs = c(0.5, 0.5)` as `sample` by default will use 50/50 since you're only giving it two options. You would use `probs` if you wanted it to be a 70/30 split for male/female.

```
df$gender[df$gender == ""] <- sample(c('male', 'female'), length(df$gender[df$gender == ""]), replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: `Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$gender == "", value = c(3L, 3L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated` All the rows turn to NA

Comment: Convert to character first. `df$gender <- as.character(df$gender)` then try it.