# How to replace missing categorical data from large dataset in R?

Tags: r, replace, r-markdown, na, missing-data

I use the dataset from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shilongzhuang/telecom-customer-churn-by-maven-analytics 
Here there are many categorical values with missing datapoints. I am not sure how to deal with these missing values. Since almost every row has at least one missing value I can't just delete the rows. Using mean/mode also is not applicable to this dataset.

What can I do best to handle these missing values?

For example I tried to impute the variable Multiple.Lines like this:

```
telecom_customer_churn $ Multiple.Lines = impute(telecom_customer_churn$Multiple.Lines, "random")
```

This works, but when I try to make a bar plot like this:

```
ggplot(data = telecom_customer_churn) +
  geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = Multiple.Lines),  color = "blue", fill = "lightblue")
```

It shows me the error:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

This is weird to me because the all the missing values of Multiple.Lines are replaced by either 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: This isn't really an R question. Here is an article that explains how you can deal with missing values in R though: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/04/handling-missing-values-in-r/

Comment: I have to deal with this in R. When I'm using the impute function for categorical data it returns a numerical value which is not what I need. For example the variable Multiple.Lines has values of 'yes', 'no' and 'NA'. I want to replace the NA value with either yes or no in proportion to the rest of the data. I can't figure out how to do this

Comment: This makes it clearer. In your question here, you should also add a reproducible example of the code you tried so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693993/r-replace-empty-column-of-df-with-random-categorical-value

Comment: No sadly it doesn't. I edited my question. The problem lies with the making of the plot.

Comment: It really depends on the (statistical) method you want to apply to impute the data. A useful package you might want to have a look at is `mice`

Comment: OK now after seeing your edit your concern seems to be the plotting, not the imputation of data. Does this help? `ggplot(telecom_customer_churn, aes(x = Multiple.Lines)) +geom_bar(color = "blue", fill = "lightblue")`

Comment: When I use this code I still get the error "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Comment: It's weird because my whole column looks like this                                                                                                                    
Multiple.Lines
<S3: impute>
Internet.Service
<chr>
Internet.Type
<S3: impute>
 No  
 Yes  
 No  
 No  
 No  
 No  
 No  
 Yes  
 No  
 Yes

Comment: Can you provide a minimally reproduceable example? The following works for me: `telecom_customer_churn = data.frame(Multiple.Lines = c(rep("yes",5),rep("no",7), rep("maybe",3)))`
`ggplot(telecom_customer_churn, aes(x = Multiple.Lines)) +geom_bar(color = "blue", fill = "lightblue")` You might also go with `geom_histogram()` instead of `geom_bar()` but then you should convert your categorial variables to numeric variables first

Comment: Which package did you use to impute data?

Comment: Normally that code would work on the variables. I get a perfect bar graph. However when I impute the categorical values like Mulitple.Lines with the function impute(). The error Discrete value supplied to continuous scale occurs. If I try to manually replace all missing values of Multiple.Lines it probably would work but there are too many values so it would take too much time.

Comment: I used the Hmsic package to impute the variables.

Comment: `telecom_customer_churn $ Multiple.Lines = impute(telecom_customer_churn$Multiple.Lines, "random")

ggplot(telecom_customer_churn, aes(x = Multiple.Lines)) +
  geom_bar(color = "blue", fill = "lightblue")
` This just gets me the error. If I skip the first part (imputing the data), I will get a bar plot, but the missing values are included in this plot

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to your problem:
The problem was that the object type was changed to "impute". Applying `as.factor()` forces the data to be read as categorial once again.

```
library(Hmisc)

telecom_customer_churn = data.frame(Multiple.Lines = c(rep("yes",5), NA, rep("no",7), rep(NA,2), rep("maybe",3)))
telecom_customer_churn$Multiple.Lines = impute(telecom_customer_churn$Multiple.Lines, "random")

ggplot(telecom_customer_churn, aes(x = as.factor(Multiple.Lines))) +geom_bar(color = "blue", fill = "lightblue")
```

Comment: You're welcome! Calling `class(telecom_customer_churn$Multiple.Lines)` after the first and the second line you can see how it changes from "character" to "impute".